# GeSHi code editor for the web

Tags: php, ide, code-editor, geshi

**hi :)** 
*(sorry if my english is not perfect :/ )*
im trying to make a code editor for my site, i want to color automatically code written by users at the some time they tape it.
i found this php script which use GeSHi to color code . my problem is that i can't use it in textarea :/ 
someone talked about using fieldset but i cant understand how :/

```
include("geshi/geshi.php");

$source = $req;
$language = 'php';
$path = 'geshi/geshi/';

$geshi = new GeSHi($source, $language, $path);

echo $geshi->parse_code();
```

**could someone help me ? :) thank you :)**

Comment: You can't do this with GeSHi because it doesn't offer editing capabilities, it only syntax-highlights your markup. Take a look at [CodeMirror](http://codemirror.net/) instead

Comment: thank you @onetrickpony :) im going to take a look :)

Comment: Geshi parse the code server side. You should be parse it using client side so the user can edit the code live. Take a look at http://ace.c9.io for example or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_JavaScript-based_source_code_editors for looking at all of them. ACE is Canvas based and you should strive for that for better performance.

Answer (score 1):

Geshi can't do that since it run on server side. You may use a JS code highlighter like [CodeMirror](http://codemirror.net) or  [highlight.js](http://highlightjs.org) which run on client side.